# passing array or slice into variable args function in golang

Tags: go

filepath.Join method takes in a `...string` argument but I have a `[]string` that I would like pass in.  When I attempt to do this I get the following error:

```
cannot use append(elems, spadePath) (type []string) as type string in argument to filepath.Join
```

Is there a way to convert between a []type and a ...type?

Answer (score 15):

Found a way to do this by appending the `...` to your slice when being passed in as an argument.

For example, I was originally trying to call make the following call which was yielding the error:

```
filepath.Join(append(elems, basePath))
```

but I corrected it by appending `...` in the argument:

```
filepath.Join(append(elems, basePath)...)
```

Comment: This does work - Thanks alot!!